# How do I work with a Canvas / JCanvas in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, canvas, jcanvas

In netbeans it is possible to add a canvas to your app, however it does not seem possible to draw on the canvas because you need to overload the paint(Graphics) method. What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just write a class that extends Canvas / JCanvas then drop it onto the GUI designer from the navigator pane.